Serverless config for scheduled lambda function
I have a lambda function configured in serverless to run on a schedule as follows:
  runDailyBatch:
    handler: src/handlerRunDailyBatch.handler
    timeout: 20
    reservedConcurrency: 1
    memorySize: 128
    events:
      # Min, Hr, Day-of-month, Month, Day-of-week, Year
      - schedule:
          name: "api-data_pipeline_runner-${opt:stage}-daily"
          method: scheduler
          rate: cron(*/3 * * * ? *)
          # TODO: rate: cron(10 2 * * 1-6 *)
          timezone: Europe/London
          input:
            cause: 'daily'
    alarms:
      - name: functionErrors
        nameTemplate: "$[functionName]_function_errors"
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - states:StartExecution
        Resource: ${self:resources.Outputs.RunBatchStateMachine.Value}
    lambdaInsights: true

If I remove the "method: scheduler" and timezone elements it works but then it'll be executing at the wrong time when we hit DST (note that the every-3-minute times are just for testing purposes) which is clearly undesirable.
I believe I've followed the instructions at https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule#:~:text=key2%3A%20value2-,Use%20AWS%3A%3AScheduler%3A%3ASchedule%20instead%20of%20AWS%3A%3AEvent%3A%3ARule,-Note%3A%20scheduler correctly but it doesn't work.
I see the schedule under Eventbridge schedules correctly but no trigger on the lambda and then lambda never executes.
What am I missing? Permissions? If so, why are there no error reported anywhere?

The offending block is this:
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - states:StartExecution
        Resource: ${self:resources.Outputs.RunBatchStateMachine.Value}

This appears to overwrite the role used for the schedule as well as that for the lambda. The workaround is to remove this and put it under provider / iam.
